# Which tier should I choose on Uffizzi Cloud for a smaller but growing application?

Tags: automation, hosting, devops

My application currently has around 5k regular users and is growing by about 100 users per month. I am considering having it deployed on this new Uffizzi cloud so that I don't have to think so much about maintaining my deployment but am not sure what level I need at my size or if I will outgrow the lower tier soon.

Answer (score -1):

Much will depend on your application is built and how it handles requests.

The Standard Tier is designed for anything that is for Dev and Test purposes or anything that just a few people will be accessing.  Good use cases are running your app in a Dev, QA, or Staging environment so you can see how it is working before it goes live to an audience (this process is very important - most features don't come out of the box working exactly as everyone on the team expected them to - or at least as your product lead expected them to)

The Performance Tier has auto-scaling and is a good choice for a public facing app that you don't want to crash under load or have delays serving up responses.  If you have users in the 10s to 100s this is appropriate.

The Enterprise Tier is a good choice for several 100 to hundreds of thousands of users. The key decision is how reliable do you want your app to be.  Obviously if you have an outage at any point that may hurt your reputation and the more people using your app the worse it will be. The Enterprise Tier has automated High Availability.  This means your app will be deployed and load-balanced across three data centers also known as "AZs" (Availability Zones).  You've effectively decreased your risk factor of a hardware failure or any other incident that would cause an outage by a factor of three.